# appsrc element in gstreamer

Tags: gstreamer-1.0, gst-launch-1.0

I find this example of gstreamer pipeline:

```
gst-launch-1.0 appsrc name=mysource ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```

But I am unable to find example of the app (here it will have name **mysource**). Does, anyone know how this app should look like.

Comment: I think I found solution on my own. I will post it as a answer when I test it.